# Pygame Using Arrow Keys to "Look Around"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am currently trying to code a series of rooms, here referred to as nodes. You start out in the first room/node (node1) facing north, and the image for north is displayed. If you press left/right/down on the arrow keys you face towards the corresponding point on the compass and the new image for that direction is displayed. If you press the up arrow key while facing north in the first node you proceed to the second node.

However when I execute this code, any key press results in me proceeding to the second node. I looked through and I feel like the use of AND statements ought to make this a non-issue but clearly I am missing something within these loops.

Thanks in advance for your help...

```
def node1():
    node1_here = True
    node1_look_north = True
    node1_look_south = False
    node1_look_east = False
    node1_look_west = False
    node1_north_image = pygame.image.load('node1north.jpg')
    node1_south_image = pygame.image.load('node1south.jpg')
    node1_east_image = pygame.image.load('node1east.jpg')
    node1_west_image = pygame.image.load('node1west.jpg')
    while node1_here:
        while node1_look_north:
            screen.blit(node1_north_image, (0, 0))
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and pygame.K_UP:
                    node2()
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and pygame.K_DOWN:
                    node1_look_south = True and not node1_look_north
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and pygame.K_LEFT:
                    node1_look_east = True and not node1_look_north
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    node1_look_west = True and not node1_look_north
        while node1_look_south:
            screen.blit(node1_south_image, (0, 0))
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and pygame.K_DOWN:
                    node1_look_north = True and not node1_look_south
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and pygame.K_LEFT:
                    node1_look_west = True and not node1_look_south
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    node1_look_east = True and not node1_look_south
        while node1_look_east:
            screen.blit(node1_east_image, (0, 0))
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and pygame.K_DOWN:
                    node1_look_west = True and not node1_look_east
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and pygame.K_LEFT:
                    node1_look_south = True and not node1_look_east
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    node1_look_north = True and not node1_look_east
        while node1_look_west:
            screen.blit(node1_west_image, (0, 0))
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and pygame.K_DOWN:
                    node1_look_east = True and not node1_look_west
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and pygame.K_LEFT:
                    node1_look_north = True and not node1_look_west
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    node1_look_south = True and not node1_look_west

def node2():
    node2_here = True
    node2_look_north = True
    node2_north_image = pygame.image.load('node2north.jpg')
    while node2_here:
        while node2_look_north:
            screen.blit(node2_north_image, (0, 0))
            pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation**:

```
pygame.K_UP
```

^this is a constant and is always true. As such,

```
elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and pygame.K_UP:
```

^this will always resolve to **`True`** when you press any key, resulting in

```
node2()
```

being executed.

**Solution**:

```
elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_UP:
```

^this will check to see if the key pressed is `K_UP`

Hope that helps!

Reference:
[Pygame key docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html)